# SQL : I have two tables on table is contain the following table

Tags: python, mysql, sql

`table A` is contain `CIF_Key` and  `current date` column and many more columns

`table B` is contain `CIF_key` and  `pre_date` column which is different from `date` variable in Table A and many more columns.

my Goal  :is to see if there is same record from table B in table A and if it exists I need to drop them from table A based on the condition that if the difference between the current date column and pre_date column is less than 4 month else I want to keep them in table A.
how can I do this goal ?

Comment: So what have you done so far to achieve your goal

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: Do you need to check ALL the columns, or is a `CIF_key` match enough?

Comment: drop the rows in table  A if conditions  the difference between the current date column and pre_date column is less than 4 month  else keep them in table A with same values of columns in table A

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts  CIF_Key was enough

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can `JOIN` the tables using the common `CIF_Key` - here is some info: [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Then use `WHERE` to compare dates or something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a 
    JOIN table_b on table_a.CIF_Key = table_b.CIF_Key 
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, table_a.date, table_b.date) < 4;
```

Comment: I'm paraphrasing here though since I think there is more to your question and some of it can be learned by looking at SQL documentation on JOIN and WHERE clauses